# Assigning Image object to a variable

Tags: android, image, variables

I am trying to assign an Image object from the drawable folder to a variable. I searched on how to do this, and it was given in the following manner.

```
Image img = getImage(R.drawable.app);
```

But, there is an error showing  getImage is unresolved. Can anyone tell  me the correct way to do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: `getImage()` does not exists...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getImage()` does not exists...

Use `getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.xxx)` to get an "Image" (actually a `Drawable` from the *drawable* folder(s).